Selector is calling its builder every time notifylistners() is called
Selector widget is calling its builder every time notifyListeners() is called even if the selected value is not changed
To Reproduce
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as de;
import 'dart:math';
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class SomeDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier{

  List<Beaker> beakers = <Beaker>[];
  String message ='';
  
 //only changes message
  void changemessage(){
    message = Random().nextDouble().toString();
    notifyListeners();
   }
  
  //changes list and message
  void addNewBeaker(){
    int t = Random().nextInt(100);
    int te = Random().nextInt(100);
    beakers = [...beakers, Beaker(temp: te, rpm: t)];
    message = '$t and $te are added';
  //  beakers.add(Beaker(temp: te, rpm: t));
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Beaker {
  Beaker({required this.temp, required this.rpm});
  int rpm;
  int temp;
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => SomeDataProvider(),
      lazy: false,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
         colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white30,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            
            //for displaying list length
              Selector<SomeDataProvider, List<Beaker>>(
                selector: (_,sd)=> sd.beakers,
                builder: (context, data, child)  {
                  de.log('Selector<Listprovider, List<Beaker>>: builder called for change in list');
                  return Text('${data.length}');
                  },
                ),
                
              // for building message
                Selector<SomeDataProvider, String>(
                  selector: (_, sd) => sd.message,
                  builder: (context, value, child) {
                    de.log('Selector<Listprovider, String>: builder called for message changed ');
                    return Text(value);},
                  ),
                

                ListenableBuilder(listenable: context.watch<SomeDataProvider>(),
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    de.log('ListenableBuilder: builder called');
                    return Text('${context.read<SomeDataProvider>().beakers.length}');
                  }),

                  TextButton(onPressed: (){
                    context.read<SomeDataProvider>().changemessage();
                  }, child: Text('button that will only change message')),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: (){
          context.read<SomeDataProvider>().addNewBeaker();
      }),
    );
  }
} 

Expected behavior
builder should be called only if results from selector are changed?
in this example when TextButton calls the changemessage  method,  builder function from the Selector that is not concerned with displaying message is also called or am I doing something wrong?

To fix your issue and keep the UI the same as you have it. Please see the following code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as de;
import 'dart:math';
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class SomeDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier{

  List<Beaker> _beakers = <Beaker>[];
  String _message ='';

  List<Beaker> get beakers => _beakers;
  String get message => _message;
  //only changes message
  void changemessage(){
    _message = Random().nextDouble().toString();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //changes list and message
  void addNewBeaker(){
    int t = Random().nextInt(100);
    int te = Random().nextInt(100);
    _beakers = [..._beakers, Beaker(temp: te, rpm: t)];
    _message = '$t and $te are added';
    //  beakers.add(Beaker(temp: te, rpm: t));
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Beaker {
  Beaker({required this.temp, required this.rpm});
  int rpm;
  int temp;
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => SomeDataProvider(),
      lazy: false,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white30,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [

              //for displaying list length
              Selector<SomeDataProvider, List<Beaker>>(
                selector: (_,sd)=> sd.beakers,
                builder: (context, data, child)  {
                  de.log('Selector<Listprovider, List<Beaker>>: builder called for change in list');
                  return Text('${data.length}');
                },
              ),

              // for building message
              Selector<SomeDataProvider, String>(
                selector: (_, sd) => sd.message,
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                  de.log('Selector<Listprovider, String>: builder called for message changed ');
                  return Text(value);},
              ),

              Selector<SomeDataProvider, int>(
                selector: (_,sd)=> sd.beakers.length,
                builder: (context, data, child)  {
                  de.log('Selector<ListProvider>, int>: builder called for change in list');
                  return Text('${data}');
                },
              ),

              TextButton(onPressed: (){
                context.read<SomeDataProvider>().changemessage();
              }, child: Text('button that will only change message')),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: (){
            context.read<SomeDataProvider>().addNewBeaker();
          }),
    );
  }
}

Notice that I replaced the ListenableBuilder with another Selector. The way that your ListenableBuilder is set up seems to be rebuilding the entire MyHomePage each time a change was made to SomeDataProvider. Please see their example if you wish to continue to use this widget.
Additional note, the third listener widget you have is redundant as it portrays the exact number as the first listener widget.

in this example i was just trying to learn how Selector and ListenableBuilder works, could you please explain how ListenableBuilder could be placed in this widget tree?

I would take a look at the example they provided and build off of that it should be located in "examples/api/lib/widgets/transitions/listenable_builder.1.dart"

I will add, if you are just learning take a look at state management platforms. They make managing state a lot easier. I like the stacked package but there are others as well. https://stacked.filledstacks.com/
